# Google cloud "mk" error "Invalid identifier 'ch04' for mk."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am very new to google cloud and following an example in "Google BigQuery: The Definitive Guide" to learn to use this platform. I am trying to make a dataset to hold the data of a dataset and exactly typing what it is written in the book but I get the following results: Invalid identifier 'ch04' for mk.

here is a picture of the command lines
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0een.png)

Can you help me with this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I opened Cloud Shell from Google Cloud Plataform, at the right from the TERMINAL tab there's a tab with your Project Name that open a Terminal too. I typed the commands there and worked fine !

Answer (score 0):

To create a dataset from the command line you need to run a `bq mk` [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_mk).

Look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#create-dataset) official documentation as it should provide all the necessary details on how to create a dataset. To sum up you need to follow this syntax

```
bq --location=<location> mk \
--dataset \
--default_table_expiration <integer1> \
--default_partition_expiration <integer2> \
--description <description> \
project_id:<dataset-name>
```

For example:

```
bq --location=US mk -d \
--default_table_expiration 3600 \
--description "This is my first dataset." \
myfirstdataset
```

I assume that ch04 may stand for information in chapter 4 or some other in-book notation that needs to be changed accordingly to make the command work.

Answer (score 0):

In the cloud shell, See if your project is set using below command.

```
gcloud config list project
```

If it is not set, set the project id using below command

```
gcloud config set project <projectid>
```

then run the command

```
bq --location=US mk ch04
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your picture, looks like you haven't set your active project yet.

To set your active project, use the code:

```
gcloud config set project <PROJECT-ID-HERE>
```

If your project is already set, your cloudshell should start with this:

```
<login-name>@cloudshell:~ <project-id>$
```

This is mine, for example

[image: cloudshell]